# error login with csrf and jquery cookie in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i create login with javascript and codeigniter using CSRF and result after login is **False** whether there is something wrong in my code.

My CSRF :

```html
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'st21Ol02sec94';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'true6log_suc';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

my view :

```
<?php echo form_open('',array('id' => 'form-loginx'));?>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <span class="input-group-addon lab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control inp usernamex" placeholder="username" required>

        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <span class="input-group-addon lab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control inp passwordx" placeholder="password" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="log_btn btn btn-md btn-primary">Login</button>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="lihat"> lihat password</label>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
        <?php echo br();?>
    <div class="text-center">Copyright &copy; 2017 PT. Stars Internasional.</div>
    <div class="text-center">server time <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> secs.</div>
        <?php echo br();?>
    <div style="display:none;" class="alert-gagal"></div>
    <div style="display:none;" class="alert-sukses"></div>
```

my javascript :

```
$('#form-loginx').submit(function(e){ // Create `click` event function for login
        e.preventDefault();
        var csrf_hash = $.cookie('true6log_suc');
        var me = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
            type : "POST",
            url  : baseURL + "trueaccon2194/info_type_user_log/log_admin",
            data : {me,st21Ol02sec94: csrf_hash},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.log_btn').html('Loading ...'); //Loading button text 
            $('.log_btn').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function(log){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
            $('.log_btn').html('Login'); //Loading button text 
            $('.log_btn').prop('disabled', false);
            if(log == "openupsystemlogtrueaccess21"){
                $(".alert-sukses").html("Sedang mengarahkan..").slideToggle("fast").delay(3000).slideToggle("fast");
                window.location.href = 'trueaccon2194/info_type_user_log';
            }else if(log == "blockingaccesssystemlogerror210294"){
                $(".alert-gagal").html("Username atau password salah!").slideToggle("fast").delay(3000).slideToggle("fast");
                //location.reload();
            }
            }
            });
        return false;
});
```

i use jquery cookie and whether there is something wrong with my code

Comment: Just a idea I find its best to use virtual host with csrf then normal localhost url

Comment: i use localhost

Comment: So do I you can set it up simple on xampp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kD-tLlKS2ZI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with data in ajax call. The "csrf_hash" in the data will not give the exact value.

Replace the csrf with

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'st21Ol02sec94';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'true6log_suc';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

In js

```
$('#form-loginx').submit(function(e){ // Create `click` event function for login
e.preventDefault();
var csrf_hash = $.cookie('true6log_suc');
var dataObject = {};
dataObject[st21Ol02sec94] = csrf_hash;
dataObject[me] = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
type : "POST",
url  : baseURL + "trueaccon2194/info_type_user_log/log_admin",
data: dataObject,
beforeSend: function(){
$('.log_btn').html('Loading ...'); //Loading button text
$('.log_btn').prop('disabled', true);
},
success: function(log){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
$('.log_btn').html('Login'); //Loading button text
$('.log_btn').prop('disabled', false);
if(log == "openupsystemlogtrueaccess21"){
$(".alert-sukses").html("Sedang mengarahkan..").slideToggle("fast").delay(3000).slideToggle("fast");
window.location.href = 'trueaccon2194/info_type_user_log';
}else if(log == "blockingaccesssystemlogerror210294"){
$(".alert-gagal").html("Username atau password salah!").slideToggle("fast").delay(3000).slideToggle("fast");
//location.reload();
}
}
});
return false;
});
```

This may help you.